# blank space in ms word picture

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a picture that looks like this in ms word:

[image]

What might be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is anything missing from the image? Do you see the top or bottom?

Comment: Do you have the picture's source? Does it change if you scroll? What do you see if you print it out? (This is to determine if the picture got damaged inside the file or there is a problem with your computer.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the image has been offset in the y direction. To fix it:

1. Right-click on the image and select the option, "Format Picture...".
2. Select "Crop" on the left of the popped up window.
3. Edit the "Offset Y" number to 0.
4. Press the Close button.